# Definition of complex argument: E.g. what is the locus $\arg z \geq 3 \pi/4$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Say that $\arg z$ has principal values $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Then should the locus of points $z$ such that $\arg z \geq 3 \pi/4$ be understood to mean ...

1. Just the region bounded by the rays $\arg z = 3 \pi/4$ and $\arg z = \pi$, because $\arg z \in (-\pi,\pi]$.

Or ...

2. The entire plane, because every point is in the locus --- for example $-i$ is in the locus because $\arg (-i) = -\pi/2 = 3\pi/2$.

Comment: It's the first, because of your assumption that starts the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you look at it, really. When someone says $\arg(z) \geq \frac{3 \pi}{4}$, then I would imagine thay're talking about part of the plane where the angle is greater than $\frac{3 \pi}{4} = 135^\circ$

It's true that $\arg z \in (-\pi, pi]$, but people mess around with notation a little, so that "intuitive" transgressions are "okay".

Comment: The fourth quadrant is where $\displaystyle\arg z \ge {3\pi\over \bf2}$, not $4$.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want principle values and $\arg$ is between $(-\pi, ~\pi]$, you are taking a branch cut on negative real axis.
Thus choice 1. is correct region in principle plane.